# What is the time, space complexity of this code?

Tags: python, big-o

What is the time complexity of this code?

```
if not root:
    return 0 
    
if root.left is None and root.right is None:
    return 1

que = []
que.append(root)
maximum = 0
while que:
    for i in range(len(que)):
        node = que.pop(0)
        if node.left:
            que.append(node.left)
        if node.right:
            que.append(node.right)
    maximum += 1
return maximum
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are basically visiting all nodes of binary tree.

Hence, both time & space complexity is *O(N)* (n == # of nodes).

EDIT: Since you've used list for queue, time complexity is *O(N^2)*, but there is a door for the improvement which will boost performance to *O(N)*.

Detailed Info:

**Time Complexity**: You are using *list* instead of built-in queue or deque. *list*'s `append()` or `pop()` costs *O(1)* but `pop(0)` costs *O(N)*. Thus your code is not efficient. It will take *O(N^2)* just because of the data structure you've chosen to use as a queue. Use built-in `queue` or `deque` which only takes *O(1)* for inserting & poping first element. If so, time complexity will be *O(N)*.

**Space Complexity**: The algorithm traverse the binary tree one level at a time, so the maximum number of items in queue is reached at the highest level which contains leaf nodes.
Full binary tree has (n+1)/2 leaf nodes. *O((n+1)/2)* = *O(N)*.

Comment: Isn't the space complexity the memory used?  If so, it isn't N, as `que` never contains all the nodes, right? I'm not much of a theory guy, so maybe I'm wrong here.

Comment: It's not O(n) time, look closer.

Comment: @superbrain.  Why do you think it's not O(n)?  Every node is pushed onto the queue once.  Every node is popped off the queue once.  The `for i in range(len(queue))` is just noise that shouldn't be there, but doesn't affect the time of the algorithm. . . .   All this assuming root is the root of a tree.  That's never explicitly stated.  If not, who knows.

Comment: @FrankYellin `que.pop(0)` isn't O(1) but Θ(|que|).

Comment: @superbrain.  You're absolutely right.  They should be using a `Deque`.

Comment: @superbrain according to the [C++ reference](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/queue/queue/pop/) `pop()`'s time complexity is constant because it's default underlying container is `Deque`.

Comment: @Steve The algorithm traverse the binary tree one level at a time, so the maximum number of items in queue is reached at the highest level which contains leaf nodes. Full binary tree has (n+1)/2 leaf nodes. O((n+1)/2) = O(N),

Comment: @LazyRen - makes sense - I think you should add what you say in your last comment to your answer, and also possibly address the complexity of `pop()` and `append()`.

Comment: @LazyRen Um... why do you look at the **C++** reference for **Python** code? And they're not using a queue, they're using a list (or rather *abusing* a list, as a queue).

Comment: @superbrain You are right. I did not considered that the original code used list instead of queue or deque. Edit has been made to the post. Thank you for the notice.

Answer (score 0):

I also agree with the time & space complexity being `O(n)`, where n is the number of codes. However, I think a more detailed explanation of the result can be as follows (assuming the the `root` is the root of a tree):

- Time complexity: each node enters `que` exactly once and leaves `que` exactly once. When a node leaves, a maximum of 2 checks and 2 appends are performed. The program ends when `que` is empty, resulting in a time complexity of `(2+2)*n=4n --> O(n)`
- Space complexity: the `que` can hold no more than all the nodes in the graph at any time, resulting in a space complexity of `O(n)`

Comment: As said above in the comments, a fully "detailed" explanation of time complexity would have to take into account the behavior of `que.pop()` and `que.append()` as the size of `que` grows.  To state what the maximum size of `que` can be only puts an upper bound on the space complexity.  It could still be less than O(N).  As it turns out, by @LazyRen's logic, it is still O(N), but not for the reason you state.